# Adding custom transformation parameters in Reproject raster chain function in Mosaic Dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, mosaic-dataset

I have scanned maps georeferenced in custom projection with local datum. I have transformation parameters from the local datum to WGS84.

I created a mosaic dataset for the georeferenced maps with custom projection. Now I created another mosaic dataset referenced to first one to have new dataset with WGS84 datum.

I added `Reproject` function in raster chain functions and set the output projection as WGS84. There is no place to set transformation parameter from local datum to WGS84 and as a result the new raster dataset is not reprojected properly.

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Possibly use the Create Custom Geographic Transformation tool. That will at least make a transformation available to the system.

Comment: Transformation is already added in the system for on-the-fly projection on ArcMap. This information is not available on the Reproject Raster Chain function.